# Upper bound for norm of 1-body correlation tensor of qubit

Tags: quantum-information, tensor-calculus, correlation-functions

Any $n$-qubit state can be expressed as

$$\rho=\frac{1}{2^{n}} \sum_{\mu_{1}, \ldots, \mu_{n}=0,1,2,3} T_{\mu_{1}, \ldots, \mu_{n}} \sigma_{\mu_{1}} \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma_{\mu_{n}}$$

where $\sigma_{\mu_k}\in \{\mathbb{1,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}}$. The coefficients $T_{\mu_{1}, \ldots, \mu_{n}}$ are real numbers in $[-1,1]$ given by the correlation function values for measurements of products of Pauli operators

$$T_{\mu_{1}, \ldots, \mu_{n}}=\left\langle\sigma_{\mu_{1}} \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma_{\mu_{n}}\right\rangle_{\rho}=\operatorname{Tr}\left(\rho \sigma_{\mu_{1}} \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma_{\mu_{n}}\right)$$

We will call $\mathcal T$ the correlation tensor.

The paper now says, that since $\text{Tr}(\rho^2_j)\leq 1$, all 1-body correlation tensors  must obey

$$||T^{(j)}||\leq \sqrt{\frac{2(d_j-1)}{d_j}} $$
with equality iff the state is pure, where the number of superscripts denotes the order of the tensor, $||\cdot ||$ is the standard Euclidean norm for vectors and $d_j$ is the dimension of the Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}_j$.

Unfortunately, the paper does not argue, how this follows from the fact that the trace is bounded by $1$.

Does anyone know how this identity follows from the trace, or where such a proof can be found?

Thanks!

EDIT: thanks to @NorbertSchuch I now understand how the above holds for qubits with $d=2$. However, I am still unclear how the general case of $d>2$ is proven.

Comment: We are talking of one qubit here? Do you know about the Bloch sphere? And what is your question: Why pure states have ||T||=1?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63718,  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/189253.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, my question is why $||T^{(j)}||\leq \sqrt{\frac{2(d_j-1)}{d_j}} $

Comment: I do know about the Bloch sphere, though I do not immediately see how the result follows-

Comment: For a point $\vec r\in\mathbb R^3$ on the Bloch sphere, $\rho=(I + \vec r\cdot \vec\sigma)/2$ is exactly of the form above with $T=(1,\vec r)$.

Comment: Ah, ok thank you! I did not make that connection.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand well the meaning of the various symbols, the strict inequality is **already false** for $n=1$. In that case, as remarked in Norbert's answer, a generic mixed state has always the form $$\rho = \frac{1}{2}\left(t_0 \sigma_0 + \sum_{k=1}^3 t_k \sigma_k \right)\:, \quad t_\mu \in \mathbb{R}$$
where $\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^3 t^2_k}\leq 1$ **and $t_0=1$**. However what matters in the discussed formula seems to be  instead
$$||t|| = \sqrt{t_0^2 + \sum_{k=1}^3 t^2_k} = \sqrt{1+ \sum_{k=1}^3 t^2_k}\geq 1 \:. \tag{1}$$
Furthermore,
$$\sqrt{\frac{2(d-1)}{d}}= 1 \quad \mbox{if $d=2$}$$
so that we should find is
$$||t|| \leq 1 $$
contrarily to (1). 
I expect that $||T^{j}||$ is defined in a way to disregard (some? all?) $0$-components, 
since some of them are blocked.
Indeed, 
$$\rho=\frac{1}{2^{n}} \sum_{\mu_{1}, \ldots, \mu_{n}=0,1,2,3} T_{\mu_{1}, \ldots, \mu_{n}} \sigma_{\mu_{1}} \otimes \ldots \otimes \sigma_{\mu_{n}}$$
implies 
$$Tr(\rho) = T_{00\ldots 0}$$
and this trace must be $1$ by definition.

Comment: Good point. Indeed, pg 2 of the reference (unedited): *"We will de-
compose the tensor T i 1 ···i n into the m-body correlation
tensors T i j , T i j i k , etc,* ***which are tensors of order m in-
dicated by the number of labels in the superscript. All
the indices not labeled in the superscript are fixed to be
zero*** *while the other indices take every possible value but
zero (i. e. the identity is not taken into account). For in-
stance, the 1-body correlation tensor for particle 1, given
(1)
by T i 1 = T i 1 0···0 with i 1 6 = 0, completely characterizes
the reduced state ρ 1".*

Comment: Thank you both for your help, and I'm really sorry if I'm being dense here, but why is $Tr(\rho)=T_{00...0}$? Why do you know that all other $T_{ii.....i}$ are zero?

Comment: Because $Tr(\sigma_k)=0$ for every $k=1,2,3$ and $Tr(A_1\otimes \cdots \otimes A_n) = Tr(A_1) \cdots Tr(A_n)$ if the $A_k$ act on corresponding *pairwise different* Hilbert spaces. Therefore, the only surviving trace is the one which acts on a term which  does not contain factors $\sigma_k$ with $k=1,2,3$. Only $\sigma_0 \otimes \cdots \otimes \sigma_0$ is of this sort.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is nothing but a different way of stating the well-known fact that points on the surface of the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) are pure:

For a point $\vec r\in\mathbb R^3$ in or on the Bloch sphere, $\rho=\tfrac12(I+\vec r\cdot\vec \sigma)$ is precisely of the form you give for $n=1$ and with $T=(1,\vec r)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I now understand the case of $d=2$, but I am still unclear how the general case of $d>2$ is proven.

Comment: In the general case, I don't think there is such a statement: It is non-trivial to determine the shape of the Bloch "sphere", i.e. the set of all $T$ such that $\rho$ is positive semi-definite.  See e.g. the links I provided above in the comment.

Comment: The paper I am reading claims the general statement without proof: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.5756.pdf (see page three eq. (3))

Comment: @Pentaquark Presumably their $T^{(j)}$ is different from just $T$.  It is on you to figure out what it is.  But if it is the $T$ for the reduced 1-qubit density matrix, the qubit statement holds.